# printf ouput is being destroyed by a "\n" after scanf

Tags: c, printf, scanf

printf is ouput is being destyoryed by a "\n" after I run scanf. I am attempting to use.

```
scanf ("%*c");
```

to chomp the "\n" but its not working... here is the code

```
    printf("Enter char float int char:", char4, deci2, num2, char5);
    scanf ("%c %f %d %c", &char4, &deci2, &num2, &char5);
    scanf ("%*c");
    printf("You entered: '%c' %.3f %d '%c' " ,char4 ,deci2, num2, char5 );
```

and it outputs to

```
    Enter char int char float:a 5 a 5.5
    You entered: 'a' 5 'a' 5.500 
    Enter char float int char:a 5.5 6 b
    You entered: '
    ' 0.000 0 ''
```

Comment: What are you trying to do in:  `printf("Enter char float int char:", char4, deci2, num2, char5);`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line

```
scanf ("%c %f %d %c", &char4, &deci2, &num2, &char5);
```

is picking up the stray newline left in the input buffer from your previous `scanf` call.  You can work around that by putting a space in front of the first `%c`:

```
scanf (" %c %f %d %c", &char4, &deci2, &num2, &char5);
```

This will tell `scanf` to skip over any leading whitespace (blanks, newlines, tabs, etc.) before reading the next non-whitespace character.

The line

```
printf("Enter char float int char:", char4, deci2, num2, char5);
```

is a bit of a head-scratcher; it won't cause any problems (the excess arguments are evaluated, but otherwise ignored), but it looks wrong, and indicates some confusion.

Answer (score 3):

In this line:

```
printf("Enter char float int char:", char4, deci2, num2, char5);
```

remove the `char4`, `deci2`, `num2`, and `char5`. If you're still seeing issues as Carl Norum suggests, then try consuming the newline character left over from your first scanf as such:

```
scanf ("%c %f %d %c", &char4, &deci2, &num2, &char5);
getchar();
printf("You entered: '%c' %.3f %d '%c' " ,char4 ,deci2, num2, char5 );
```

Comment: That line of code is wrong, but isn't the OP's problem, I think.

Comment: @CarlNorum - I checked it quick and the code works for me after that change. However there could defiantly be more than one problem.

Comment: @Mike, that's because he didn't provide enough code.  If you left that stuff in, it would work exactly the same for you.  Deleting those won't change any behaviour on most compilers (though it does, technically speaking, cause undefined behaviour).

Comment: opps. lol. quietly finishing my cup of coffee. Thank you. Still getting the `   You entered: '
    ' 0.000 0 ''1` as the output.

Comment: @user1787331, that's because this answer is wrong, despite having garnered 4 upvotes.

Comment: @Mike, your edit doesn't fix anything - the OP's `scanf("%*c")` and your `getchar()` call are the same.  The problem is in code the OP didn't show us.

Answer (score 2):

It's the remaining `\n` in the buffer from your *first* read that's still hanging around.  You need to eat that one *before* doing the second `scanf`, not after.

Editorial note:  You should really include all of the relevant code in your question rather than just a subset.  I could only infer this to be your problem from the output you provided.  It contains the string `Enter char int char float` which isn't present in your example code.

Comment: When I saw `printf("Enter char float int char:", char4, deci2, num2, char5);` I stopped looking at the code :D

Comment: Sure, that's *bad*, but it's unlikely to cause problems.

Comment: @MarounMaroun when I read this comment, I quit looking at my code, and started looking for my coffee!

Comment: +1 for noticing - `You should really include all of the relevant code`

Comment: Thank you. This helped me understand where my problem was occurring.